# How to bind a collection to a table in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a razor component including a simple table that I want to use as an input table as following:

```
<label for="dependencies">Abhängigkeiten</label>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Version</th>
    <th scope="col">Entfernen</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the code section I have a property of type `IEnumerable<T>` that I want to bind dynamically to the table, so the content of the collection gets binded to the table. Which options do I have to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach(var item in AllItems)
{
  <tr @key=item>
    <td>@item.Name
  </tr>
}
```

You can also do `<InputText @bind=item.Name/>` if you need to.